# why in react flux: component this.state is updated automatically when store changed?

Tags: reactjs, state, store, flux, refluxjs

I am confused why in component as bellows, this.state is automatically changed when corresponding store updated?

The compoenent is listening to MyStore. Once the number there changed, it will call `onchange()` in the component, which is supposed to get the new number from store by calling `this.getStateFromStores()`. It works.  However, my question is: I added this line `const alreadyHasNewData = this.state;` to check `this.state` before `getStateFromStores()`.
Debug found that `this.state` is already updated in sync with store, how come this could happen?

Any help thanks!

```
class My-component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = this.getStateFromStores(); // default number is 8;
    }

    private userClicked() => void = () => {
        int newNumber = 9;
        MyActionCreators.userClicked(newNumber);
    };

    private onChange: () => void = () => {
    // Why this.state is already has new number in store, which is 9?
        const alreadyHasNewData = this.state;

    // I think only this line will get updated number in store, which is 9.
        const data = this.getStateFromStores();

        this.setState({
            weekMeetingCardData: data.weekMeetingCardData     
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(): void {
        MyStore.addListener(this.onChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(): void {
        MyStore.removeListener(this.onChange);
    }

    protected getStateFromStores() {
        return {
            MyStore.getNumber();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine. Which debugger did you use to check the numbers? If unsure, maybe using `console.log()` will help. NB: make sure you debug or log the number, NOT the object.

Comment: I used chrome to debug, and I do debug by inspect number real stored in it. My confusion is: why in onChange() method, this.state is already updated to store's new number without calling this.getStateFromStores()?

Comment: In chrome, if you `console.log()` an object (such as `this.state`), you can inspect the contents of the object in the console, but the contents DO NOT necessarily give you the values at the time of logging. In your `console.log(...)`, what do you have in the `...`?